# Is empty 'docker-machine ls' output valid when 'docker ps' shows running containers?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

I have docker for windows running on windows 10.  I think its working correctly. I saw something interesting and wanted to ask if anyone had any thoughts on this.

I have two docker images running.   The command "docker ps" lists them (below).  When I run "docker-machine ls" I get nothing.  Shouldn't "docker-machine ls" also have results?

```
E:\Public\docker>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8c4b5b2fd86b        obd-sdk                   "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:8009->80/tcp     obdsdk
32a05196bcb3        obd-registrationservice   "java -Djava.secur..."   20 hours ago        Up 20 hours         0.0.0.0:8110->8110/tcp   obdregsvc

E:\Public\docker>docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

E:\Public\docker>
```

Thanks,
Matt

Edit:  this is a screen shot of a second windows 10 machine in which I do have dockertoolbox/kitematic running with Hyper-v.
[image]

Comment: This may help: https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/#what-is-docker-machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`docker-machine` is used as a part of Docker Toolbox.

Docker Toolbox is `Virtual Box + Docker Machine + boot2docker unix image with docker + Kitematic`

Docker for Windows is `Hyper-V based Moby Linux with Docker`. So you are not using docker toolbox that is why `docker-machine ls` is empty. While `docker ps` is showing you results. Docker for windows tries to give you more native experience with docker compared to Toolbox.

For more details refer to below links

https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/#what-is-docker-machine
https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Comment: I thought that as well.  And the documentation supports this.   

Where I get lost with that information is I do have dockertoolbox/kitematic running on another windows 10 machine with Hyper-v.   So that information isn't 100% correct.  I will add, however, 'docker-machine ls' returns the same results on that computer as well.

Comment: Kitematic is compatible with both Hyper-V and Toolbox. But Kitematic is not distributed as a part of Docker for Windows